# Casting List of object and Get the Result

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I'm Trying to cast a list to an object like:

```
public static List<Object> lstproductname = new List<Object>();


var partialResult = db.Company.OrderBy(x => x.id).Take(1);
            var finalResult = (from j in db.productListDbSet
                               join comp in partialResult
                               on j.mstr_company_id equals comp.id
                               select new { j.id, j.name }).OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();

            lstproductname = finalResult.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Trying to use foreach as a result but no luck..

```
            foreach (var d in lstproductname.ToList())
            {
                string s =   d.ToString();
            }
```

`lstproductname` has a content like `{ id = 1, name = "Product1" }`

I need to get the `id value` and the `name value` but unfortunately can't get it..

I tried something from foreach like

```
foreach (var d in lstproductname.ToList())
            {
                string id =   d.id.ToString();
                string name = d.name.ToString();
            }
```

This one is not working..

```
 string id =   d.id.ToString();
 string name = d.name.ToString();
```

Any idea how to get this is Highly Appreciated.

Comment: Why cast to `object`, why don't you loop through `finalResult`?

Comment: Because this is just the only way to get my needs.. i tried so many times in other way but using object is just the only one give me a success result. but my problem is the extracting of the content.

Comment: it a function that contains  a `List<Object>`.

Comment: Create a model with properties `int ID` and `string Name` and use `select new yourModel { ID = j.id, Name =  j.name }` (don't use `object`)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen it seems like that's my second chance.

Comment: Just don't return anonymous types from any method. *At least* you could use `Tuple` if it's for internal use, or the newer C#7 tuples

Comment: Thanks @Stephen i think its work.. i add new model like you advised.. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

Create a new class

```
public class FinalProduct
{ 
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**LINQ**

```
        public static List<FinalProduct> lstproductname = new 
        List<FinalProduct>();

        var partialResult = db.Company.OrderBy(x => x.id).Take(1);
        var finalResult = (from j in db.productListDbSet
                           join comp in partialResult
                           on j.mstr_company_id equals comp.id
                           select new FinalProduct {id= j.id,name= j.name }).OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();

        lstproductname = finalResult.Cast<FinalProduct>().ToList();
        foreach (var d in lstproductname.ToList())
        {
            String id = d.id.ToString();
            String name = d.name.ToString();
        }
```

Solution idea from `@Stephen Muecke` Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `object`.  cast to a concrete class or something. Declare this:

```
class ResultItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then do this:

```
var finalResults = (from j in db.productListDbSet
                           join comp in partialResult
                           on j.mstr_company_id equals comp.id
                           select new ResultItem{ Id=j.id, Name=j.name })
    .OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList();

foreach (var result in finalResults)
{
    string id = result.Id.ToString();
    string name = result.Name.ToString();
    //do stuff...
}
```

Comment: thanks for this answer but seems like doesn't change anything.

Comment: @reds Then I don't understand your comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47326018/casting-list-of-object-and-get-the-result#comment81604023_47326018)

Comment: @reds - this should work.  the reason you have problems is simply that `object` does not have `Id` and `Name` properties.  In theory you could cast the object to an appropriate type, but since your `select new{...` is creating an *anonymous* type you cannot do this.  You need to *either* have a concrete class as in my example to create, so you know what the type is, *or* you need to omit the `.Cast<object>()` so you directly pass back the anonymous type.  What error are you having with my suggestion?  I've just realised that I've capitalised Id and Name (rather than id and name) - is it that?

Comment: I know this should work but you removed the object List instead of redirecting the variable itself. Thanks

Comment: The solution is creating a new class with an `id` and `name`.